# How to Populate REST APIs with Azure Data Factory Pipeline with Multiple Entries

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to establish a way of ingesting multiple company data with Azure Data Factory using HTTP Link Service.

The below image shows how to ingest a single data source or a single entry using the HTTP link

https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/06999618.json

[image]

The above would give me the financials for a single company. If we want to ingest the financials of another company with company id of 07803944 we would have to replace the above link with

https://duedil.io/v4/company/gb/07803944.json

For obvious reasons it would not be practical to have a copy activity or pipeline for every company we need the financials for.

Therefore, can someone let me know if's possible to parameterize the link service to ingest multiple companies in the same copy activity? Alternatively, simply add individual company ids to the link service?

I tried the following, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Here's a rough guide on how you dynamically populate the RESt API task (and any task for that matter) https://www.thedataswamp.com/blog/dynamically-calling-rest-apis-in-azure-data-factory

Comment: I have applied the guide in the blog, however I'm getting the following error ```Error
{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'length(activity('Countries Lookup').output.value)' cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist, available properties are 'firstRow, effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "For Each Country",
    "details": ""
}``

Comment: I changed the property from value to 'firstRow' and the error disappeared. However, I am now getting the following Error ```{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "For Each Country",
    "details": ""
}```

Comment: Nearly there. I'm now just getting the following error ```{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=HttpRequestTimedOut,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The HTTP request to the RESTful API timed out. HttpRequestTimeout is configured as '00:01:40'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Rest to ADLS",
    "details": []
}```

Comment: ok, figured out why I was getting the last error. Now getting error ```{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=DnsResolutionFailure,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=restcountries.comslovakia could not be resolved.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy Rest to ADLS",
    "details": []
}```

Comment: Working fine now. Thanks Nick

Comment: Great. It would be awesome if you documented your solution as an answer to help others.